# SwiftUI Page style TabView with dynamic height

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to create a `PageTabViewStyle` `TabView` where views inside can be of different heights. I need to get the height of the largest view and set it as the height of the TabView. That would be easy enough with GeometryReader and just updating `height` with `max(height, viewHeight)`, but the GeometryReader will not update the height until it appears on the screen. Is there some way I can get the `height` of the largest view even when it is not on the screen yet?

Here is the code I have tried, where the `TabView` will get updated after a swipe.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue, .gray, .teal]
    let elements = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    @State var height: CGFloat = .zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            TabView {
                ForEach(elements, id: \.self) { element in
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(element)")
                                .font(.title)
                            Spacer()
                        }

                        .frame(height: 100 + CGFloat(30 * element))
                        .background {
                            GeometryReader { geometry in
                                colors[element].preference(
                                    key: TabViewHeightKey.self,
                                    value: max(geometry.size.height, height)
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
            .onPreferenceChange(TabViewHeightKey.self) { height = $0 }
            .frame(height: height)

            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Color.white
                        .frame(height: 100)
                    Color.purple
                        .frame(height: 200)
                    Color.orange
                        .frame(height: 300)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TabViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = max(value, nextValue())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the height of the tallest page by showing all the pages in a hidden `ZStack`, layered one on top of each other. The `TabView` can then be shown in an overlay over the `ZStack`. You don't even need to set the height of the `TabView`, because the overlay automatically adopts the height of the view it is applied to.

Here is your example with the adaptions applied:

```swift
private var allPages: some View {
    ForEach(elements, id: \.self) { element in
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("\(element)")
                    .font(.title)
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(height: 100 + CGFloat(30 * element))
            .background {
                colors[element]
            }
        }
    }
}

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        ZStack {
            allPages
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .hidden()
        .overlay {
            TabView {
                allPages
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
        }
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Color.white
                    .frame(height: 100)
                Color.purple
                    .frame(height: 200)
                Color.orange
                    .frame(height: 300)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is weird, but it works well. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it seems weird because the ```ZStack``` is hidden. But hiding a view does not remove it from the layout, it just makes it non-visible. So it is a good way of establishing a footprint for a view to be shown in an overlay. Anyway, thanks for accepting the answer!